# Cómo mostrar una Progress Bar al tocar un botón?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Tengo este botón que al tocarlo muestra mi progress bar, el problema es que estoy usando el mecanismo de Acordiones de Bootstrap 5. Y aunque funciona bien, la idea es que al tocar varias veces el botón, **la barra ya no se oculte.**

Hay alguna forma de corregirlo? O cómo podría hacerlo sin Jquery?

PD: Ya probé agregando `aria-expanded="true"` pero no funcionó.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="inicio" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mostrar" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="mostrar">Iniciar</button>
<div class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="inicio" id="mostrar">
  <div class="progress border">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated bg-warning text-white" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de investigar un tiempo, logré hacerlo con Vanilla Javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("inicio").onclick = function() {
  var z = document.getElementById("prueba");
  // reviso si el elemento ya está oculto
  if (z.style.display == 'none') {
    z.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<!--SCRIPT PARA MOSTRAR ELEMENTO CON BOTÓN Y NO OCULTARLO-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="inicio">Iniciar</button>

<div class="progress border" id="prueba" style="display: none;">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated bg-warning text-white" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```